# Can hibernate session be assisgned to a instance variable of a Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have assigned hibernate session to **instance variable** of an immutable class. The class uses this session object (instance variable) to create hibernate query. The code works fine.

Due to this is it possible that the connection pool does not have free connections to database.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by ` is it possible that the connection pool does not have free connections to database.`?

Answer (score 0):

Session will take a single connection from the connection pool. Other connections will be free. Please refer the [Hibernate manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html),

*It is advisable to have the org.hibernate.SessionFactory create and pool JDBC connections for you. If you take this approach, opening a org.hibernate.
Session is as simple as:

Session session = sessions.openSession(); // open a new Session

Once you start a task that requires access to the database, a JDBC connection will be obtained from the pool.*